# Django not recognizing a module from another directory

Tags: python, django, bitnami

I use [Django with bitnami](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/infrastructure/django/get-started/get-started/). The problem is with importing [this](https://github.com/openai/whisper#available-models-and-languages) package (follow the link to see the installation instructions that I followed).

This is where I was able to find the package that I installed:
/home/bitnami/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages

This is just a path where I do not see the needed package:
/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages

This did not work: (I tried all the sys.path.append strings separately as well):

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render

import sys
sys.path.append('/home/bitnami/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/whisper')
sys.path.append('/home/bitnami/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages')
sys.path.append('/home/bitnami/.local/lib/python3.8')
sys.path.append('/home/bitnami/.local/lib')

import whisper

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse(sys.modules.keys());
```

If I remove 'import whisper', then the code works but 'sys.modules.keys()' does not output the needed module (it is named 'whisper').

This may be of help (after the command goes the output that I see):

```
$ echo $PATH
    /home/bitnami/.local/bin:/opt/bitnami/apache/bin:/opt/bitnami/apache2/bin:/opt/bitnami/common/bin:/opt/bitnami/gon
    it/bin:/opt/bitnami/mariadb/bin:/opt/bitnami/mariadb/sbin:/opt/bitnami/node/bin:/opt/bitnami/postgresql/bin:/opt/b
    itnami/python/bin:/opt/bitnami/nami/bin:/opt/bitnami/apache/bin:/opt/bitnami/apache2/bin:/opt/bitnami/common/bin:/
    opt/bitnami/gonit/bin:/opt/bitnami/mariadb/bin:/opt/bitnami/mariadb/sbin:/opt/bitnami/node/bin:/opt/bitnami/postgr
    esql/bin:/opt/bitnami/python/bin:/opt/bitnami/nami/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your Django project's main settings.py file and add the following line at the beginning of the file:

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/bitnami/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages')

# Other Django settings follow...
```